# Matchfunction for my UserForm in VBA to update my database

Tags: excel, vba

Sorry im pretty new in VBA but hard working to get into it :)

I have created a userform in VBA where the input from the userform gets transfered into different columns in a database on another sheet.
The identitynumber i have in mind is unique and can be called NR for simplicity

Now i need an extra function that when the collection is done we receive another number that i will use to put into a new Inputbox together with the specific identitynumber.

So the new userform im thinking of will have 3 inputboxes, one for date, one for the identify number and one for the new number.
When putting in all of the above i need somehow that it goes through column F in Sheet"Data" and find the relevant identynr and add the new number in column H in Sheet"Data" and also the date in column i on the same row as the actual identify nr.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I've come up with...

- Name the three text boxes txtDate, txtNR, txtNew
- Create a command button, I didn't bother renaming (CommandButton1)
- Inside the click event for the button add the following code

  `Dim rng1 As Range
  Dim strSearch As String
  strSearch = txtNR.Text
  Set rng1 = Range("F:F").Find(strSearch, , xlValues, xlWhole)
  If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then
      rng1.Activate
      rng1.Offset(0, 2).Value = txtNew.Text
      rng1.Offset(0, 3).Value = txtDate.Text
  Else
      MsgBox strSearch & " not found"
  End If`

Once you click on the button, the procedure will search column F for the value in txtNR and add the value of txtNew in column H and the txtDate in Column I.

Hope this helps, let me know if you require any additional information or have any troubles with this method.

Comment: If you wish to use the current date in the date text box use `Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    txtDate.Value = Format(Date, "mm/dd/yyyy")
End Sub
`